# Contar registros si campo fecha es nulo con Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una tabla "reactivos" relacionada con una "stockreactivos", en la cual en ésta última voy agregando reactivos en los cuales entre sus datos está el campo "fecha_baja".
El tema es que en el index de "reactivos" aparecen listados obviamente todos los reactivos, pero agregué una columna donde quiero sumar los que tengo en "stockreactivo" de cada uno de ellos, para lo cual quiero sumar todos los que no están de baja.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega algo de Laravel/Eloquent a la pregunta. Lo que tengas hecho, si esas tablas tienen un Modelo Eloquent, si estás trabajando en un Controlador y lo que hayas intentado para obtener los datos de la BD.

Answer (score 1):

Al trabajar con Eloquent, la función para Where campo is null de sql se obtiene de la siguiente forma

```
$elements = Model::whereIsNull('campo')->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, pero lo pude solucionar poniendo ésto en el controlador: withCount(['stockreactivos as stock' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('fecha_baja', null);}])